# TYPO3: Rename flux fields and keep the values?

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux

Usually when renaming a flux field, the old values are not transfered and have to be entered again. Is there a way to keep the values after renaming a flux field?

Let's look at this simple flux configuration for example:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="article" icon="{f:uri.resource(path: 'Icons/Content/Example.svg')}" options="{group: 'FCE'}">
        <flux:field.text name="text" rows="1"/>
    </flux:form>
</f:section>
```

If I now rename the field `text` to `title` all previously entered values for `text` are lost:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="article" icon="{f:uri.resource(path: 'Icons/Content/Example.svg')}" options="{group: 'FCE'}">
        <flux:field.text name="title" rows="1"/>
    </flux:form>
</f:section>
```

Is it possible to somehow let flux know, that the field `title` is supposed to have the values of the former field `text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

> If I now rename the field text to title all previously entered values for text are lost

Long answer: in fact, they are still present in stored XML from FlexForm, but with old name. There are two reasons for this:

1. This is not technically possible to determine, that the field was
   *renamed*. Because the end result is same, as field was *deleted* and a *new was created*.
2. Imagine a situation, that you have two page templates, where first one contains field of name `text` and second - `title`. You set first template as page template and fill `text` with something. Then you change template to second one - should now `title` contain previously filled value? Then you switch back to the first template - should the `text` be restored (in fact it is restored, because Flux doesn't delete it)? And now combine it with inheritance of templates and see, which mess can happen.

Comment: You are right, it makes sense that just renaming a field is handled the way it is. I was thinking maybe there is some possibility of restoring the values though, maybe by assigning unique identifiers to fields or by executing a script that parses the database and updates the flexform. But apparently there isn't (yet). Thank you!